# Is there a tight upper bound on $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m \min(a\cdot i,b \cdot j)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Is there a tight upper bound on $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m \min(a \cdot i,b \cdot j)$ for any $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^+$

For example one upper bound would be
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m \min(a \cdot i,b \cdot j) \le \min \left(a \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m i,b \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m j \right)
\end{align}

Is there a better approach??
Thank you

**Edit:**

Note that w.l.o.g. we can set $a=1$.

Comment: Split the problem into cases and calculate the double sum. You can look at the intervals $[a,na]$ and $[b,mb]$ and assume without loss of generality that $a<b$ (because of symmetry). Then the intervals can be disjoint or overlap in several ways, in each case giving you an explicit value for the minimum. For the actual calculations, all you need is the fact that the sum of the first $n$ positive integers is equal to $n(n+1)/2$.

Comment: @herrsimon could you explain a bit more. Why intervals $[a,na]$ and $[b,mb]$?

Comment: These are the extremal values of $ai$ and $bj$.

Comment: I do one simple case for you: Still assuming $a<b$, if $[a,na]$ and $[b,mb]$ do not overlap, i.e. $na \leq b$, then $ai \leq an \leq b \leq bj$ which implies that $\operatorname{min}(ai,bj)=ai$. Therefore, $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m \operatorname{min}(ai,bj) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m ai = a \sum_{i=1}^n  i \sum_{j=1}^m = a m n (n+1)/2$. The overlapping cases are a bit trickier but work analogously.

Comment: Thanks. I will try. Do yo mind if I bug you a little more with question if I don't succeed?

Comment: Try and if you have more questions, ask them. If I'm not here to answer them, I'm sure that somebody else will. By the way, just to give you a better understanding: For finite sums, there is always a tight upper and lower bound, namely the value of the sum, which you (or a computer) can explicitly calculate.

Comment: Yes. I need an analytical one though

Comment: @herrsimon I've been try to analyze all the cases but keep running into issues. Could help me with identifying all the cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This upper bound is surely not the tightest, but it's a cool approach i believe:

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m \min(a \cdot i,b \cdot j) \le & \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m \frac{a \cdot i+b \cdot j}{2}=\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a \cdot i}{2}+\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m \frac{b \cdot j}{2}=\\
&=\frac{am}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n i+\frac{bn}{2}\sum_{j=1}^m j=\\
&=\frac{am}{2}\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+\frac{bn}{2}\cdot\frac{m(m+1)}{2}=\\
&=\frac{mn}{4}\Big[a(n+1)+b(m+1)\Big]
\end{align}
$$
so more concisely:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m \min(a \cdot i,b \cdot j) \le \frac{mn}{4}\Big[a(n+1)+b(m+1)\Big]
$$

by the way your upper bound can be written more concisely:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m \min(a \cdot i,b \cdot j) \le \frac{mn}{2}\min\Big(a(n+1),b(m+1)\Big)
$$
so you found a better upper bound apparently :D

---

mini-proof for: $\ \ \ \ \ \min(a,b)\le\frac{a+b}{2}$
given $a,b \in \mathbb{R}| a \le b$:
$$
min(a,b)=a\\
a\le b \iff a+a\le b+a \iff \frac{a+a}{2}\le \frac{a+b}{2} \iff a\le \frac{a+b}{2} \implies\\
\implies\min(a,b)=a\le \frac{a+b}{2}
$$
if $a>b$ just swap the letters in the proof :)

---

writing min(a,b) as an analytic function:
$$\min(a,b)= \frac{a+b-|a-b|}{2} = \frac{a+b-\sqrt{(a-b)^2}}{2} $$

Comment: Question. Is $min(a,b) \le \frac{a+b}{2}$??

Comment: always, i edited my answer and i added a mini proof for that inequality.

Comment: Hey. Is there a way to write min(a,b) is an analytic function? Maybe that can work?

Comment: there is a cumbersome way to do it, re-edited the answer.

Comment: Yes. But this will not solve it. Because $|a-b|$ doesn't sum well.

Comment: you could do $|a-b| = \sqrt{(a-b)^2}$ but i doubt that helps..

Comment: Yes. I just tried. It does not.

Comment: search this on wolfram alpha: $\ \ \ \ \mbox{sum_(i=1)^n sum_(j=1)^m min(i,j)}\ \ \ \ $ i'm, starting to believe that what you are looking for does not exist...

Comment: since this question has kept me busy, i decided to upvote it!

Comment: By doesn't exist you mean no one ever tried it?

Comment: no, what i meant was more like: it cannot be done the way you want it... the only reasonable way would be to examine cases, like someone suggested in the comments to your question.

Comment: I see. But I think some cases a very difficult and probably can not be done as well.

Comment: @Franceso Alem  Do you think I should put it as a bounty question? Is this interesting to the community at all or not?

Comment: i do not think you'll get an answer that deserves the bounty, but try if this problem is really important to you :)

Comment: Thanks. You see all I am looking for is the bound that is slightly better than the one I have. Even by a constant.