# Is there a way to re-write $\min(a,b)$ in terms of an analytical function?

Tags: functions

Is there a way to re-write $\min(a,b)$ in terms of an analytical function?

Also, if not, is there a nice analytic function that is a tight upper bound?

This question is related to  this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936963/is-there-a-tight-upper-bound-on-sum-i-1n-sum-j-1m-mina-cdot-i-b-cdot/937046#937046).

Comment: But absolute value is not analytic. Right?

Comment: What do you mean by a $\textbf{tight}$ upper bound?

Comment: @Alex The $\min$ function isn't analytic!

Comment: That's what I though. Because it's not differentiable. Is there a nice upper bound that is differential?

Comment: @DPoole I guess, something that upper bounds it well.

Comment: @Alex Upper bound in absolute value or not? There aren't many real-valued analytic functions $f(z=a+bi)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

$$\min(a,\,b) \; = \; \frac{a\,+\,b\; - \; |a-b|}{2}   $$
$$\max(a,\,b) \; = \; \frac{a\,+\,b\; + \; |a-b|}{2}   $$

Comment: Almost, except that absolute value is not analytic? right?

Comment: @Alex: you can replace $|a-b|$ by $\sqrt{a^2-2ab+b^2}$

Comment: I was assuming you meant "analytic" in the sense of some kind of explicit expression, not in the "analytic" sense involving power series stuff.

Comment: @robjohn is $\sqrt{a^2-2ab+b^2}$ an upper bound on $|a-b|$ or lower bound?

Comment: @Alex: it is *equal* to $|a-b|$

Comment: @Alex: Note that $\sqrt{u^2} = |u|$ and $a^2 - 2ab + b^2 = (a-b)^{2}.$

Comment: Yes. I know. It's just me not thinking